# How to use IndyLaz without installing it?

Tags: debian, lazarus, indy10

I'm using Lazarus, and I need IndyLaz to create my application, so I downloaded the last version, I compiled it but I had some installation usses, so I decided to use it without installing it in my IDE.
As I know, all i need to do is to add the class of the component (example:TIDHTTP):

```
uses IdHttp;
```

And then, declare a variable:

```
var http:TIDHttp;
```

Normally, that's all. But during the compilation of my application I got this compilation error:
"Can't find IdHttp used by unit1".
Is there something wrong?
Thanks for your replies.

Comment: `Project Options -> Paths -> Other unit files` add paths to Indy units. Or open `indylaz.lpk` and `Use -> Add to Project`.

Comment: Or just describe your task and I or somebody else will provide examples how to solve it using LNet/Synapse/InternetTools libraries.

Comment: thanks, I tried the two suggetions but I'm having the same error. Well it's a  download application, I also tried lNet, I installed it in lazarus, I saw the example of using http component but it didn't help me a lot; I want to use it without SSL. So assuming that URL is: "localhost\myfile", and the URI is "/home/Emily/mydownloadedFile", could you give me an example of code on how to realise this? sorry I tried many, but it didn't work.

Comment: I don't know what just happened, but I tried to install it again, and that was successful. No need to use another library, indy is just perfect. Thanks for your assistance.